# Angular 2 percent pipe incorrect output

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to utilize the Angular percentage pipe:

```
 80 | percent: '1.2-2'"
```

I'm expecting an output of **80.00%** but instead I'm getting **8,000.00%**

What exactly I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not Angular **2** any more since a little while now. Either write Angular 2+ or just Angular.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `0.8 | percent: '1.2-2'"`

Since angular multiplies it by 100 it becomes 80